# SQL show first name of player with max(height) from each team

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm learning SQL and have to find the highest player from each team (4 teams in total, 2 players per team). I've done this, but now I have to find the name of these players. However, it only shows the name of the first player from each team instead of the name of the highest, while still showing the correct height.

I'm working with two tables:

```
players: player_id, last, first, team_id, number
player_data: player_id, height, weight
```

This is the SQL code that's currently not working:

```
SELECT p.team_id, p.first, MAX(pd.height)
FROM players p, player_data pd
WHERE pd.player_id = p.player_id
GROUP BY p.team_id
```

I hope you can help!

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @BrianPatterson How that help?

Comment: `SELECT p.team_id, p.first ... GROUP BY GROUP BY p.team_id`  is invalid ANSI SQL.. it works in MySQL but only if sql-mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is off.. But it will generate invalid results for the column p.first because it's not in the GROUP BY..  https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: By "Highest", Do you mean tallest?

Comment: Please use explict joins not implicit (comma separated) joins.(who still teaches this stuff)

Comment: University student questions are always easy to identify as many professors continue to teach this join syntax.

Comment: Hockey teams, I hope!

Comment: @jarlh Doesnt Hockey teams have 6 players?

Comment: try my answer...

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, usually not. (I couldn't find the number of players specified.)

Comment: maybe http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4eee7/5

Comment: @RossBush Yes, I'm a student and we're being taught implicit joins atm., but we'll probably be taught explicit soon. We've only had one lesson so far.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Yes, the tallest player.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Have a sub-query that returns each team's max height.

```
SELECT p.team_id, p.first, pd.height
FROM players p
JOIN player_data pd
    ON pd.player_id = p.player_id
WHERE (p.team_id, pd.height) IN (SELECT p.team_id, MAX(pd.height)
                                 FROM players p
                                 JOIN player_data pd
                                     ON pd.player_id = p.player_id
                                 GROUP BY p.team_id)
```

Comment: I think you need a DISTINCT in one of your queries in case two players with the same name and height are on the same team.

Comment: @RossBush, I'd rather return both of them!

Comment: @RossBush Yes I also saw the same. But think the same as jarlh. So maybe add a footnote. If both players have same height, then both players will be returned

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. My friends and I've been trying with subqueries, but didn't understand them properly. This makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using row_number() over(partition by) instead of group by. The below query partitions the data by teamid order by height and the where condition would select the first row selected.

```
select * from (
Select p.team_id,p.first,row_number() over(partition by p.team_id order by pd.height desc)rn
from players p, player_data pd
WHERE pd.player_id = p.player_id)
where rn = 1
```

Comment: mysql doesnt have row_number();

Comment: MySQL 8.0 has row_number() @JuanCarlosOropeza https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html

Comment: @RaymondNijland I know, but as you said, Isnt production ready yet.

Comment: *MySQL 8.0 is a development series not recommended for production use.* - [see here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/)

Answer (score 0):

boom

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4eee7/5

```
select p.teamid, p.playerid, p.firstname, p.lastname,
   pd.playerid, pd.height, pd.weight
from players p, player_data pd 
where p.playerid = pd.playerid
group by p.teamid
order by pd.height
```

Comment: This may work. But be aware of `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` setting. Also if both players have same height you will get a random one.